# Replacing elements of sub-arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following array:

```
arr = array([[[-9, -9,  1],
        [-9,  0,  4],
        [-9, -9,  1]],

       [[-9,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  4,  3],
        [-9,  1,  2]]])
```

for each element, I want to go through the 1st row and if the first element and last element of that were not equal to zero I would like to replace them with zero. The out put should look like the following:

```
array([[[-9, -9,  1],
            [0,  0,  0],
            [-9, -9,  1]],
    
           [[-9,  1,  1],
            [ 0,  4,  0],
            [-9,  1,  2]]])
```

where we look up on `[-9,  0,  4]` and `[ 0,  4,  3]` and turn them into `[0,  0,  0] and` [ 0,  4,  0]`. I have tried to to the following: for the first element I wrote:

```
for i in arr:
    print(np.where(i[1][0]!=0, 0, i[1]))
```

then for the second element I wrote:

```
for i in arr:
    print(np.where(i[1][2]!=0, 0, i[1]))
```

I was planning to join the results and replace them in the arr but my second for throws wrong result. I also think there must be a much better way.

Comment: by "first row" do you mean the row with index 1???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the first element and last element of the 2nd row in each sub array to zero, you can just do:

```
arr[:,1,[0,-1]] = 0

arr
#[[[-9 -9  1]
#  [ 0  0  0]
#  [-9 -9  1]]

# [[-9  1  1]
#  [ 0  4  0]
#  [-9  1  2]]]
```

where in `:,1,[0,-1]`, `:` specifies all subarrays, `1` specifies the 2nd row in each subarray and `[0,-1]` chooses the first and last element in the row.